# How to determine if the device is battery-less or not using c++ program

Tags: power-management, c++, battery

I have a requirement to determine if the device on which my c++ application is running is battery less or not. I didn't find a standard way to do this.
I found some terminal commands such as **upower -d** which gives an attribute **'on-battery': yes/no**. But is upower installed by default on all linux systems? If not what else can be used?

Thanks!

Comment: What Unix are you running?

Comment: I am running it on Linux system

Answer (score 0):

You can check battery status from shell using
`cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status`. Since /sys/class (`sysfs` pseudo file system) is available on all Linux systems, you can call this from C++ safely. Perhaps make some checks first for other batteries also, all enumerate status for all batteries.

Comment: ok. But the intent is to know whether the device has a battery or not. Suppose if I run this command cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status in a battery less device, then there I suppose BAT0 folder wont be present. Therefore, it will crash saying No such file or directory.

Comment: Check for the presence of `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT*` file then.